# Sending MMS with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sms, mms

I'm looking for a way to programmatically send text + image in SMS message using Flutter (so basically an MMS). Hope anyone could help me out here.

Comment: did you get any?

Comment: Nope. I ended up implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging, where I could then push images and text to a given user's device.